# Elasticsearch multinode environment

Tags: elasticsearch

In elastic search i created multi-node setup.I use Java Api transport Client to communicate to Elasticsearch server.

Now i created transport client with only one IP[assume:192.129.129.12.9300]. If i request any query in single ip it communicates all nodes and returns results. What happen if it my node[192.129.129.12.9300] that i mentioned in transport Client fails. Can i communicate with other nodes. What is the optimum way configuration to use transport Client for multi node set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate `sniff` option.

See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html#transport-client